# How can I add another collaborator to my trigger.io project?

Tags: trigger.io

Right now my collaborator gets an error like this: [  ERROR] Forge API call to app/f7617c848[...]adcbe/should_rebuild went wrong: App matching query does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're working on team features, but for now it's a bit awkward -  the way you work on a shared project is to:

- each do a 'forge create'
- keep your own identity.json which is created in the src subdirectory
- share the rest of the code