# Trigger.io .gitignore

Tags: git, trigger.io

Noticing when I do builds for my Trigger.io app I get tons of new files in `.template/` and `development/`.

Should I be git ignoring these files? Any advice or `.gitignore` files you want to share?

Comment: 90% of the time you really only need to source control everything in your 'src' directory.

Comment: seriously no idea why i'd get downvoted for this... seems like a pretty reasonable question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only files you need to keep in source control are in your `src` directory. In there, you can also exclude `identity.json` as different developers should have their own identity.

[How can I add another collaborator to my trigger.io project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822272/how-can-i-add-another-collaborator-to-my-trigger-io-project)

So, if you're git repo is one level up from src, I'd have this in my .gitignore:

```
development
release
local_config.json
forge-error.log
src/identity.json
```

Of course, another option (which I tend to favour) is to only source control `src` and just include `identity.json` in your .gitignore...