# Trigger.io Collaboration

Tags: javascript, git, github, trigger.io

Hey I'm collaborating on a Trigger.io project and I'm curious if there is documentation on how to best do this? I have other guys who are loading my project into their environments (via github) using TriggerToolkit, and they can't run the projects because there are conflicts with identity.json.

Comment: I found this answer helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822272/how-can-i-add-another-collaborator-to-my-trigger-io-project#framed-by-olark

Comment: +1 for @botbot's link - I'm going to be covering this in a webinar this Wednesday (5th Aug '12) too. We are fleshing out a better way to do team collaborations right now, but for now, everyone having their own identity.json is the way forward.

Comment: keep me posted @James, i'd be glad to help and test it out as well.

Answer (score 1):

We're working on a simpler way for team collaboration, but for now the process for importing and existing Trigger.io will be similar to the instructions here for one of our demo apps:
https://github.com/amirnathoo/Sales-Square

Basically each app you create has a unique `src/identity.json` file which is also specific to your account. You should avoid checking in your src/identity.json file and a collaborator should create their own by creating a new app and then copying your code into the `src` directory.

**Update**: we've now enabled better collaboration with our Projects launch announced last week:
http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2013/01/15/introducing-projects/

This should remove the need to manually create / overwrite the `src/identity.json` file to share Trigger.io app code