# Trigger.io index.html not found in app (ios, android emulator)

Tags: trigger.io

Having issues running my app both on android and ios. When I run my app, emulators run fine, but the emulator devices say there is no index.html in the project when there is. Not sure exactly where to begin to debug. Everybody else on my team can load the app but me. I've tried completely reinstalling TriggerToolkit but couldn't get anywhere. Don't get any errors in the logs while the ios emulator is running, just a popup message in the emulator 
"Error No index.html found in app. Mobile apps require an index.html".

When I run `forge build ios` I get this:

```
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.11
[   INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools
[   INFO] Configuration is unchanged: using existing templates
[  ERROR] Failed to parse command line arguments at ios
```

When I run `forge build android` I get this:

```
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.11
[   INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools
[   INFO] Configuration is unchanged: using existing templates
[  ERROR] Failed to parse command line arguments at android
```

Have a feeling this is because I'm working in a collaborative environment and something is getting mangled, just not sure what.

I'm using this method for collaboration: [How can I add another collaborator to my trigger.io project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822272/how-can-i-add-another-collaborator-to-my-trigger-io-project#framed-by-olark)

Comment: Lots of questions in one here! First, the command is just "forge build" rather than "forge build ios" or "forge build android". As for the missing index.html, it's not clear how all your files are laid out in your app. Usually you have a folder called e.g. "MyApp" and then inside it you have an src directory. Could you show us how your files are laid out?

Comment: More information needed as its clear your setup/config is foo.

Comment: ok, thanks @monk i should have paid more attention to the command line instructions. i was getting the error because i was running forge build ios and forge build android when i *should have* been running 'forge build' *without* ios / android. seems to be working now, thanks!

Comment: there's somebody trolling trigger.io and downvoting all my questions... lame.